# Drupal8 - Import content in custom content-type with Drush and Migrate Source CSV module

Tags: csv, drupal, import, drupal-8

I am trying to import a csv of "houses" with 480lines and 20columns in my frist Drupal8. 
I use this [module](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_source_csv).

I created a content-type "Group" with multiple custom fields in the Admin.

I create the config file as we can see on [this page](https://www.mtech-llc.com/blog/lucas-hedding/migrating-using-csv)

I do not use Drush, i'm working with ftp transfer in the company server. I don't know if I can do it using the drupal administration or another module.

Right now the config file is not validated by the import, I fixed multiples erros but it still not ok.
Do you have some examples of the config file ? Alternative to Drush ? Or another way to import CSV on D8 ? 
Thank !

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fixed it after few day and thank to the drupal.slack <3
This [page](https://www.mtech-llc.com/blog/lucas-hedding/migrating-using-csv) had help me a lot. Also this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YGiae2pGuc0).

**STEP 1 :** Config file. You'll find few examples. 
Need to be imported on : admin/config/development/configuration/single/import
with Type : "Migration"

This is mine

```
  dependencies:
  module:
    - migrate_source_csv
id: groupimport1
label: 'Import groups'
migration_groups:
  - groupe
type: content_type
source:
  plugin: csv
  path: C:/wamp64/www/drupal/espacedomicile/themes/custom/espacedomicile/files/importgroup.csv
  header_row_count: 1
  keys:
    - field_groupe_numero
process:
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: groupe
  title: field_nom
  field_groupe_numero: field_groupe_numero
  field_nom: field_nom
  field_adresse: field_adresse
  field_groupe_code_postal: field_groupe_code_postal
  field_nom_commune: field_nom_commune
  field_groupe_communaute_de_com: field_groupe_communaute_de_com
  field_groupe_nombre_de_logements: field_groupe_nombre_de_logements
  field_groupe_nombre_collectif: field_groupe_nombre_collectif
  field_groupe_nombre_individuel: field_groupe_nombre_individuel
  field_groupe_equivalent_logement: field_groupe_equivalent_logement
  field_groupe_gaz: field_groupe_gaz
  field_groupe_gaz_chauffage_coll: field_groupe_gaz_chauffage_coll
  field_groupe_electrique: field_groupe_electrique
  field_groupe_niveau: field_groupe_niveau
  field_groupe_t1: field_groupe_t1
  field_groupe_t2: field_groupe_t2
  field_groupe_t3: field_groupe_t3
  field_groupe_t4: field_groupe_t4
  field_groupe_t5: field_groupe_t5
  field_groupe_t6: field_groupe_t6
  field_groupe_t7: field_groupe_t7
  field_groupe_garage: field_groupe_garage
  field_groupe_jardin_terrasse: field_groupe_jardin_terrasse
  field_groupe_parking: field_groupe_parking
  field_groupe_dependance: field_groupe_dependance
  field_groupe_local_associatif: field_groupe_local_associatif
  field_groupe_ascenseur: field_groupe_ascenseur
destination:
  plugin: entity:node
```

**STEP 2 :** I do not find alternative to drush then I transfered the site on local (with WAMP) and I install composer + drush (master last version for D8). 
Then type the command on the recommended page above after having imported your config file.

```
drush ms
drush mi yourconfigid
```

I had problems because of my CSV file.

- I remplace ";" by ",".
- I also had to change the type of fields. Text values couldn't be matched with numercial type field.
- The path of my csv was an url. I had to but a local one : C:/wamp64/www/drupal/espacedomicile/themes/custom/espacedomicile/files/importgroup.csv

Import done \o/ what a journey to do somehting on D8